# Not render when there are too many columns

Tags: chart.js

I'm implementing a horizontal scroll chart using chartJs.
But there is a problem when I add too many columns in the chart and it does not render all the columns
[my problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyB2b.png)
I refer to this jsFiddle to implement my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/EmmaLouise/eb1aqpx8/3/
Please check my code here:

The Css code:

```
.chartWrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.chartWrapper > canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.chartAreaWrapper {
  width: 600px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

The Html code:

```
<div class="chartWrapper">
  <div class="chartAreaWrapper">
  <div class="chartAreaWrapper2">
      <canvas id="chart-Test" height="300" width="1200" style="max-height:200px"></canvas>
  </div>
  </div>
  <canvas id="axis-Test" height="300" width="0"></canvas>
</div>
```

The js code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function generateLabels() {
        var chartLabels = [];
        for (x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
            chartLabels.push("Label" + x);
        }
        return chartLabels;
    }

    function generateData() {
        var chartData = [];
        for (x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
            chartData.push(Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1));
        }
        return chartData;
    }

    function addData(numData, chart) {
        for (var i = 0; i < numData; i++) {
            chart.data.datasets[0].data.push(Math.random() * 100);
            chart.data.labels.push("Label" + i);
            var newwidth = $('.chartAreaWrapper2').width() + 60;
            $('.chartAreaWrapper2').width(newwidth);
        }
    }

    var chartData = {
        labels: generateLabels(),
        datasets: [{
            label: "Test Data Set",
            data: generateData()
        }]
    };



    $(function () {
        var rectangleSet = false;

        var canvasTest = $('#chart-Test');
        var chartTest = new Chart(canvasTest, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: chartData,

            options: {
                tooltips: {
                    titleFontSize: 0,
                    titleMarginBottom: 0,
                    bodyFontSize: 12
                },
                legend: {
                    display: false
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            fontSize: 12,
                            display: false
                        }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            fontSize: 12,
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                },
                animation: {
                    onComplete: function () {
                        if (!rectangleSet) {
                            var scale = window.devicePixelRatio;                       

                            var sourceCanvas = chartTest.chart.canvas;
                            var copyWidth = chartTest.scales['y-axis-0'].width - 10;
                            var copyHeight = chartTest.scales['y-axis-0'].height + chartTest.scales['y-axis-0'].top + 10;

                            var targetCtx = document.getElementById("axis-Test").getContext("2d");

                            targetCtx.scale(scale, scale);
                            targetCtx.canvas.width = copyWidth * scale;
                            targetCtx.canvas.height = copyHeight * scale;

                            targetCtx.canvas.style.width = `${copyWidth}px`;
                            targetCtx.canvas.style.height = `${copyHeight}px`;
                            targetCtx.drawImage(sourceCanvas, 0, 0, copyWidth * scale, copyHeight * scale, 0, 0, copyWidth * scale, copyHeight * scale);

                            var sourceCtx = sourceCanvas.getContext('2d');

                            // Normalize coordinate system to use css pixels.

                            sourceCtx.clearRect(0, 0, copyWidth * scale, copyHeight * scale);
                            rectangleSet = true;
                        }
                    },
                    onProgress: function () {
                        if (rectangleSet === true) {
                            var copyWidth = chartTest.scales['y-axis-0'].width;
                            var copyHeight = chartTest.scales['y-axis-0'].height + chartTest.scales['y-axis-0'].top + 10;

                            var sourceCtx = chartTest.chart.canvas.getContext('2d');
                            sourceCtx.clearRect(0, 0, copyWidth, copyHeight);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        addData(300, chartTest);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems there are multiple issues about this in their git repo: [Wide Bar Chart not rendering all bars](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/8309), [Non-Rendering Chart with Extended Width & Pixelated Chart Lines](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4909).

Solution seems to be to disable the clipping. This can be done in V2 like so:

```js
Chart.helpers.canvas.clipArea = function() {};
Chart.helpers.canvas.unclipArea = function() {};
```

For V3 it should be enough to just add `clip: false` to your options object.

Comment: Thank bro alot,
It worked but it still does not render the column label, it only renders the Bar. Can you have any idea?